# Find an index of integer in an array in cython

Tags: python, cython

I try to implement a bsearch function in cython over a python object array (which will be ultimately passed to the same function). The code so far is:

```
# cython: language_level=3
from cpython cimport array as arr
cimport cython
import array
from libc.stdlib cimport bsearch

cdef int CustCmp( const void *a, const void *b ) with gil:    
   cdef int a_v = (< int*>a)[0]
   cdef int b_v = (< int*>b)[0]

   if a_v < b_v: return -1
   elif b_v < a_v: return 1
   else: return 0

def Indexer():
    cdef arr.array a = arr.array('I',(3,3,4,7,7,7,7,7,8,9))
    cdef int *pa = < int*>a
    cdef int x = 7
    cdef int *p  = < int*>bsearch( &x, pa, 10, sizeof( int ), &CustCmp )

    if ( p != NULL ):
        print( "{0}".format(p-pa) )
        return p-pa
   else:
        return -1
```

However, I am getting "Python objects cannot be cast to pointers of primitive types" from `cdef int *pa = < int*>a`. What should I do to make bsearch work with a python object?

Comment: Why did you declare `a` as `const void*` in the first place if you were just going to cast it?

Comment: Because, that is how cython cimports the bsearch (https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libc/stdlib.pxd) or am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting your objects to pointer types.  This simply gives you the address, as stated in [the Cython docs](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#type-casting):

> To get the address of some Python object, use a cast to a pointer type like `<void*>` or `<PyObject*>`.

`int*` is also a pointer type, so you are not actually converting the Python `array` object into a *bona fide* C array.  Instead, you are (trying to) convert it into an invalid pointer-to-int that actually points to a Python object.  Cython recognizes that this is illegal and prevents it (this is a lot more generous than C, which would simply allow the cast and then probably crash at runtime).

The "correct" way to do this is to use a typed memory view, as the documentation describes in some detail in [Pass data from a C function via pointer](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#pass-data-from-a-c-function-via-pointer).  But the TL;DR is to write something like this:

```
cdef int[:] pa = a
cdef int *p  = < int*>bsearch( &x, &pa[0], 10, sizeof( int ), &CustCmp )
```

Note that the `if not pa.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']: ...` code shown in the documentation can be omitted, because:

> If you are using Python arrays instead of numpy arrays, you don’t need to check if the data is stored contiguously as this is always the case. See [Working with Python arrays](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/array.html#array-array).

Finally, you *probably* do not need `with gil` on your comparator function, as I cannot see it doing anything that requires the GIL.

Comment: Thank you for the help! But, it does not work. There is a new error: Invalid operand types for "-" (int \*; int[:]), from print( '{0}'.format(p-pa) ). Also if I create an explicit memory view over the array, then the speed benefit of using bsearch will be minimal. I usually do not set the gils (on contrary, used to remove them), but I cannot compile without gil for a reason: "Cannot assign type 'int (\*)(const void \*, const void \*)' to 'int (\*)(const void \*, const void \*) nogil'". It still does not work though, because of the primary  '-' (int \*; int[:]).

Comment: Yes, that's supposed to happen.  It's not a pointer anymore, so you can't treat it like one.  You have to use the goofy `&pa[0]` syntax.  That other error indicates that you should write `nogil`, not `with gil`.  Finally, the only overhead here is in the initial creation of the memoryview and the conversion to a pointer (the latter is quite minimal AFAIK), not in the subsequent binary search.  Both of those constant-factor overheads are drowned out by the cost of calling `Indexer()` from Python, which is enormous (you have to set up a Python stack frame object and do other silly things).

Comment: But if I pass different arrays to Indexer (billion of times actually), than each time I need a memory view. I wonder what will be my gain. I will try the rest of the suggestions soon. Really appreciating your help.

Comment: passing the pointer via `&a[0]` instead of creating a temporary typed memory view is more efficient and probably more straight forward.

Comment: @ead: Yes, that can be done as shown [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/array.html#zero-overhead-unsafe-access-to-raw-c-pointer) but it is less safe because there is nothing to stop the array from changing length (e.g. in another thread) and invalidating the pointer.  The memoryview explicitly asks the array object for a stable pointer via the buffer protocol.  Because this requires additional care in handling, I am reluctant to recommend it.

Comment: @Ivaylo This is misleading to say, that this solution doesn't work. Your code has more than one issue (because the example is not minimal?) and it is not Ok to expect to fix us all of them.

Comment: Apologies, if I stepped over some borders. I just tryed the '&a[0]' solution and I also find it better than a memoryview. Just to say that the array is not going to be changed ever by another thread. But how to extract the index at the end. The print(p-&a[0]) causes: Cannot take address of Python object

Comment: @Ivaylo: Please ask a new question for that.

Comment: @Kevin I haven't thought about this scenario. So without being sure that creating a memory view is really a performance bottle-neck, one probably should opt for the safer approach with typed memory views.

Comment: Sorry, but if it is a thread safe pass of an array, why memoryview. Passing the pointer should be enough, not?

Comment: @Ivaylo: I am writing this answer primarily for the people who find it in the future via Google, not for your specific use case.  Those people may have requirements which differ from yours.

Answer (score 0):

Solution of Kevin is safe and should be default in a bigger project, where you just don't know how your function is going to be used - so it is an advantage to know, that the underlying buffer is locked and no elements can be added to it from another thread - that means the pointer we pass to the C-routine isn't going to be invalidated.

If the function would have the signature with typed memory view, it would even be possible to use it for `array.array` and other buffers, like numpy-arrays, e.g.:

```
def Indexer(int[:] a):
```

This answer tries to answer the question, what is the overhead of typed memory view compared to the unsafe solution with `array.array`. For that we consider the following example, it is simpler but the timings are similar to the original function:

```
%%cython
cimport cython
import array
from cpython cimport array

def with_array(array.array a):
    cdef int *pa = a.data.as_ints #I used wrong syntax in my comments sorry for that!
    return pa[0]

def direct_memview(int[::1] a):
    return a[0]

def create_memview(a):
    cdef int[:] pa=a
    return a[0]
```

And now:

```
>>> import array
>>> a=array.array('i',range(1000))
>>> %timeit with_array(a)
160 ns ± 8.62 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

>>> %timeit direct_memview(a)
706 ns ± 22.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

>>> %timeit create_memview(a)
732 ns ± 19.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

So basically the the safe-function is 4 times slower, clearly it becomes less the more work is done in the function.

Another interesting observation: The [documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/array.html#safe-usage-with-memory-views) refers to the `direct_memory` as no-overhead, and to `create_memview` as `overhead`, but the difference is not that much (even unclear whether exists!) compared to the unsafe usage.

The difference is even bigger if we pass numpy-arrays to the functions:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b=np.array(a, dtype=np.int32)
>>> %timeit direct_memview(b)
1.48 µs ± 64.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
>>> %timeit create_memview(b)
1.54 µs ± 28.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

The overhead of numpy-arrays is twice compared to `array.array`, so `array.array` seems to be a better choice for lightweight task.

My take away from this: it might be worth to use the unsafe version, but I would only do it if I'm sure that the typed memory view's overhead is really the bottleneck and there is only one thread.