# bsearch in Cython

Tags: numpy, cython

I'm learning cython's [libc.bsearch](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libc/stdlib.pxd) for trying to use Cython to get an index in a sorted array. The example is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777101/find-an-index-of-integer-in-an-array-in-cython) with modifications:

```
## test_bsearch.pyx

cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport bsearch

cdef int comp_fun(const void *a, const void *b) nogil:
    cdef int a_v = (<int*>a)[0]
    cdef int b_v = (<int*>b)[0]

   if a_v < b_v:
       return -1
   elif a_v > b_v:
       return 1
   else:
       return 0


def bsearch_c(int[::1] t, int v):
    cdef int *p  = <int*> bsearch(&v, &t[0], t.shape[0], sizeof(int), &comp_fun)
    cdef int j = <int> p

    if p != NULL:
        return j
    else:
        return -1
```

I then created a `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize


setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize([
        "test_bsearch.pyx"
    ],
        compiler_directives={'language_level': "3"}
    ),
    include_dirs=[
        np.get_include()
    ]
)
```

And compiled the code in `Win10` in command prompt: `python setup.py build_ext -i`. But running it as follows got a strange result:

```
>>> from test_bsearch import bsearch_c
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(20, dtype=np.int32)
>>> bsearch_c(x, 5)  # got 610183044
```

I know nothing about C++, so can't figure out what's wrong with above implementation. How to correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cdef int j = <int> p
```

This is casting a pointer to an int. You want

```
cdef int j = p[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate more about the correction? Why `p[0]` works? Please allow me have one more question that, when I replaced `&v` in `bsearch(&v, ...)` by `*v`, the compile error `Casting temporary Python object to non-numeric non-Python type` occurs? How to fix this?

Comment: `p[0]` is just "dereferencing" the pointer (i.e. looking up what it points at). You can use pointers as arrays in C. `*v` will be interpreted as "expand v as a tuple". I'm not sure exactly where the error comes from but `*v` has a "Python meaning" which doesn't match what you want